# How to grep some content at runtime in a makefile target?

Tags: bash, makefile, grep

**Example:**

I have a Makefile which generates some logging output and needs to grep some values from this output. I created a simplified example to demonstrate my problem:

```
RESULT = $(shell grep Value result.log)
all:
    @echo "Value: 42\nName: Foo" > result.log
    @echo "The result is: $(RESULT)"
    @rm result.log
```

The first `echo` generates the file `result.log`. Normally this could be a build process or anything else what produces a logging file. The second `echo` shall print some text to the commandline and add the resulting Value.

**Problem:**

This does not work. The file `result.log` does not exist when the `grep`-command is executed. I think it is because `make` resolves all variables first and then executes the target.

**What I tried to solve the problem:**

I rearranged my Makefile:

```
all:
    @echo "Value: 42\nName: Foo" > result.log
    @echo "The result is:"
    @grep Value result.log
    @rm result.log
```

The output on the commnadline looks now like this:

```
The result is:
Value: 42
```

But this looks not nice. I want to have the grepped *value in the same line* as my custom string.

**Question:**

How to grep some content from the produced logging output within the same makefile target?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you to jml for the correction.

Maybe you could do like this :

```
all:
    @echo "Value: 42\nName: Foo" > result.log
    @echo "The result is: $$(grep Value result.log)"
    @rm result.log
```

Comment: This will not work! You have to escape the `$` like this: `@echo "The result is: $$(grep Value result.log)"`

Comment: Please validate the answer if it resolve your question, have a nice day!